# Docker environment for laravel application without sail

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create laravel docker environment for laravel project. My file and folder structure like below

[image]

My docker file command is looks like below

```
FROM php:8.1.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
# Mod Rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite
# Linux Library
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev 
# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
# PHP Extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext intl pdo_mysql gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
COPY laravel-app/composer.json composer.json
RUN composer install
RUN composer update
```

Problem is after run docker-compose build command I'm getting the error `Could not open input file: artisan`.

Here I understand the artisan in the laravel-app folder. If I manually access in laravel-app folder and give command `composer update`. It's working fine. Question is how can I run this composer update command via docker without manual try.

Here is the full error screenshot

[image]

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-set-up-laravel-with-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-22-04 read this blog

Comment: In this doc there has no any direction about composer update.